# How to resize image slider using media queries for mobile and tablet devices?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This is a wordpress site. The image slider used here works fine for laptop and desktop, but for mobile and tablets there are some display issues (As shown in the attached screen shot).
http://www.potterandford.co.uk/property-details/?vebraid=26438819

I believe that some form of media query will be needed to target the slider and resize it as required for smaller screen sizes. I'm looking at this section of the CSS code that needs to be addressed.

```css
    .flexslider {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.flexslider {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

What I'm not sure though is this the correct approach?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.flexslider {
width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

}
```

Is anyone able to help, point me in the correct direction?

[image: Screen shot at smaller screen size]

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap to do that automatically for you.
here  you can find a lots of sliders that use bootstrap...
http://bootsnipp.com/tags/carousel

Comment: ok, i hope these likes may help ya. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/free-responsive-slider-plugins/                                             http://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/9-most-popular-free-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugins/

Comment: Sorry it wont, as I have to use the slider being used as it is part of a property deed into the site.